# Meteor web3 sendTransaction - error cannot create property 'from

Tags: web3js, meteor

Hello ethereum experts,

I got the following error in the Chrome's Javascript Console:
`ethereum_web3.js?hash=ee8d37819d18de934b202361e374522a33bbd060:3783 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'from' on string..`

I'm on an MacOS(10.12.6) and using using Meteor (1.5) + Metamask. I started geth(1.6.7-stable) with the following commandline:

<kbd>geth --datadir "net_a" --networkid 1234 --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal" console 2>console.log</kbd>

And the followings are my attempt to send a transaction:

`// Transaction object
var tnxObj = '{from: "'+fromAddr+'", to: "'+toAddr+'", value: "' + amount + '"}';
web3.personal.unlockAccount(fromAddr, "pwd123", function(err, result) {
  if (err != null) {
    console.error("Error while unlocking account: "+err);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Account unlocked!");
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({tnxObj} , function(err, result) {
      if (err != null) {
        console.error("Error while sending transaction: "+err);
      }
      else{
        console.log("Transaction Sent!");
      }
    });
  }
});`

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`tnxObj` should be an object, not a string.

Instead of

```
var tnxObj = '{from: "'+fromAddr+'", to: "'+toAddr+'", value: "' + amount + '"}';
```

just do

```
var tnxObj = {from: fromAddr, to: toAddr, value: amount};
```

Comment: Thank Mr. Edgar. I have changed the line and now, there is no exception.

Comment: However, the transaction did not get through. 

When I check the transaction in the terminal, the value of the 'to:' parameter is 'null'. In other words the recipient's address was lost.

Nonetheless, same transaction work in the geth terminal.

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Edgar, it worked! My apology if I took your time. My careless mistake. If you notice the line:

'code' web3.eth.sendTransaction({tnxObj} ...'code'

it has extra curly brackets! Took them out and it work.